# Is there a way to load images from an array with keras ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, imagedatagenerator

I'm writing a Python program that plots TESS lightcurves and puts them into a CNN to determine if they have exoplanets or not (binary image classification).

```
def predictExo(exotrainfile,noexotrainfile,testfile):

    train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
    test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
    batchsize = 32

    train_ds = train.flow(
        get_lightcurves(exotrainfile), # gets list of numpy image arrays from file
        get_lightcurves(noexotrainfile),
        batch_size = batchsize)

    test_ds = test.flow(
        get_lightcurves(testfile),
        batch_size = batchsize)
```

I'm trying to read the images into the CNN as numpy arrays instead of from a directory. I've tried using ImageDataGenerator.flow() in the same way as flow_from_directory as above, but it returns the following error message:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/mnt/c/Users/ItIsO/Documents/GitHub/exo-ml/planetai.ipynb Cell 8' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 predictExo("PS_2022.06.27_08.12.38.csv","TOI_2022.06.29_08.07.35.csv","PS_2022.07.04_02.32.20.csv")

/mnt/c/Users/ItIsO/Documents/GitHub/exo-ml/planetai.ipynb Cell 7' in predictExo(exotrainfile, noexotrainfile, testfile)
      6 test = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
      7 batchsize = 7
----> 9 train_ds = train.flow(
     10     get_lightcurves(exotrainfile),
     11     get_lightcurves(noexotrainfile),
     12     batch_size = batchsize)
     14 test_ds = test.flow(
     15     get_lightcurves(testfile),
     16     batch_size = batchsize)
     18 # BUILD CNN MODEL

File ~/miniconda3/envs/codeastrogit/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py:884, in ImageDataGenerator.flow(self, x, y, batch_size, shuffle, sample_weight, seed, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, subset)
    833 def flow(self,
    834          x,
    835          y=None,
   (...)
    842          save_format='png',
    843          subset=None):
    844   """Takes data & label arrays, generates batches of augmented data.
...
---> 70     if type(x[1]) is not list:
     71         x_misc = [np.asarray(x[1])]
     72     else:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I haven't been able to find any tutorials/docs for using flow() to read in arrays like directories so I'm not sure if it's possible, if not are there any other ways to do so?

I'm a physics undergrad (Python self-taught) so all constructive criticism welcome.

Comment: You need to be specific on "its not working", including error messages and all details.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks, just edited the post to be more specific & include the error message.

Comment: Do you have to use `ImageDataGenerator`? Just load the arrays, use `train_test_split` to get your train and test sets (or `dataset.take()` to make them). Or you can use `flow()` to make the dataset. Do you need the methods from `ImageDataGenerator`? It looks like you don't actually need it from your code, you can rescale the loaded arrays using numpy. Your error is also saying you're not including labels in your dataset.

Comment: If you want to load it like a directory because of memory constraints, you might have to stick to `flow_from_directory` or split the array into smaller ones on disk and randomly load them somehow? Arrays are usually loaded all at once into memory.

Comment: @Djinn thank you for the advice, not using ImageDataGenerator anymore and it's working out.